# Sharing the same controller without constantly USB syncing?

Tags: ps3, ps-vita-tv

I have a PS Vita TV and a PS3 but only one DualShock controller. Whenever I switch between systems I have to briefly plug the controller into the USB port of the system I wish to start using. This is becoming a bit annoying as I want to have the Vita TV tucked away.

Is there anyway to use the controller on a different system without having to re-pair it via USB?

Comment: Don't think so since it uses secure bluetooth. I'd recommend just leaving a cord on at least the Vita TV and using it plugged in (I think this still overwrites the PS3 sync though)

Comment: @PrinnyBrocka thanks. Another answer has been posted which pretty much says the same thing. So I'll give to some time to decide if you want to post an answer or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The controller is a Bluetooth device and must be paired with the console it is going to be used with. The act of plugging it into the USB port and pressing the PS button enables the pairing sync. This is confirmed on the Sony support page titled [Pair and Assign Controllers](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/947/~/pair-and-assign-controllers).

You can read more about the subject of Bluetooth pairing via [this portion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Pairing_and_bonding) of the Wikipedia page on the topic.

Your best bet to achieve what you want is to simply buy a second controller or leave an extra USB cable attached to the Vita TV so you can tuck it away.